# EasyAdminBundle Symfony delete not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony2-easyadmin

I m using symfony 3.1 + easyAdminBundle to manage the Doctrine Entities, all works good (list, show, search, sort, modify, create), expect for the delete action, if I click delete from the easyadmin panel, the page reload with with no changes (the db row was not deleted!).

Checking the code in the delete action of the easyadmin bundle:

```
//JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller

$id = $this->request->query->get('id');
$form = $this->createDeleteForm($this->entity['name'], $id);
$form->handleRequest($this->request);

var_dump($id);
var_dump($form->isValid()); // <== THIS RETURN FALSE!!
die( 1 );
```

If I manually remove the check of form->isValid it seems to work, but is this secure?

How to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just struggled with same thing for last 2 hours. There is a little issue with the way form is built - it doesn't contain any fields. Therefore when it's submitted, no form data is being sent and form is not being submitted... Unless CSRF is enabled.

Comment: could you provide your answer once again please? because page on github does not exist anymore, i  would really be happy to solve my issue